# iOS "frame layout"

Tags: ios, layout

I'm new to iOS development but I would like to start with it. I would like to create a simple application for iPad which is simular to that one from the jpg attached.

[image: layout]

Main assumptions: 
  - section A cointains some list of items representing some objects
  - I can drag and drop the element from A to B and then B cointains some graphical representation of a dragged item (some kind of canvas).
  - C contains a table which depends on what section B contains

For now, my main question is if it is possible to create such layout. I've made a research and found out something about UISplitView but as far as I've understood it supports only "two columns" layout. I'm affraid that TableView is not good for me as well (rows only).

I assume that I need (at least) 
 - controler and model for displaying A content
 - controler and model for displaying B content
 - controler for C (model the same as for B)
 - and a root controller

Am I right?

I dont have much time for creating this app, so that's why Im asking you for any clues and advise **from what should I start learning** to not waste the time...

Comment: Is your layout static or dynamic? Do you want the same layout in portrait mode?

Comment: There should only landscape model available. For now static layout is ok, but Im afraid that there will be required to have the ability to move the line between B and CD sections (rows). What's in that case?

Comment: Welcome to iOs development, luckily you'll get access to well-written and clear documentation. Please see [View Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/viewpg_iphoneos/CreatingViews/CreatingViews.html). There're two most commonly used techniques (often combined): 1. Using .xib files from Interface Builder 2. Tweaking the Layout of Your Views Manually (look for this section at the article). That is similar to `Frame-` or `RelativeLayout` at Android. We are lacking `LinearLayout`s, they are not hard to be coded yourself though.

Comment: @A-Live brings up a good point. Are you planning on using Interface Builder (IB) or are you planning on building your view layout programmatically. Using IB is the route I'd recommend.

Comment: You know. I have some Java swing expirience so, I used to create layout stuff manually to have a good control of the code. But in iOS I dont know what approach should I choose. I think, I will use IB

Comment: Hmm... I see that probably the .storyboard file would not be a good idea when creating a single view app. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you've described your layout should not be difficult to implement. If you have additional requirements (as in the question I asked) it will get more complicated. If it is a static layout you can just put your views in a container view just as you described. You can have the views hooked up to outlets on the UIViewController for the root view, or you can have controllers for individual views or subsets of views.

Perhaps you are coming from the Android world where layout views are used. On iOS there is less use of layout views. Instead any view is a container.

Comment: Thanks, you have mentioned of static/dynamic layout